# TensorFlow MLP example outputs binary instead of decimal

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to train a multilayer perseptron to classify between true or false, based on the given input.
So far I'm using the example:

> https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py

But this gives me the output as a binary value and I rather have a decimal or percentage based output.

What I've tried:

I've tried to change the optimizer for the other available ones with no success.

> optimizer =
>   tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimizer will not change the output that is actually given by the layers.

The provided example uses ReLu for the layers, which is good for classification but to model probability it wouldn't work. You would be better off with a sigmoid function instead.

The sigmoid function can be used to model probability, whereas ReLu can be used to model positive real number.

In order to make it work for the provided example, change the multilayer_perceptron function to:

```
def multilayer_perceptron(_X, _weights, _biases):
    layer_1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(_X, _weights['h1']), _biases['b1']), name="sigmoid_l1") #Hidden layer with sigmoid activation
    layer_2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, _weights['h2']), _biases['b2']), name="sigmoid_l2") #Hidden layer with sigmoid activation
    return tf.matmul(layer_2, _weights['out'], name="matmul_lout") + _biases['out']
```

It basically replaces the ReLu activation for a sigmoid one.

Then, for the evaluation, use softmax as follows:

```
output1 = tf.nn.softmax((multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)), name="output")
avd = sess.run(output1, feed_dict={x: features_t})
```

It will provide you a range between 0 and 1 for each class. Also, you'll probably have to increase the number of epochs for this to work.